# Rendering Quotation Marks in a @Html.Raw() Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Trying to render this syntax in a Partial View:

```
 @Html.Raw("<table class="table table-togglable table-hover default footable-loaded footable">")
```

..but quotation marks inside html sentence are producing problem. I tried as far:

```
 @Html.Raw("<table class=")
 @Html.Raw("&quot;")
 @Html.Raw("table table-togglable table-hover default footable-loaded footable")
 @Html.Raw("&quot;")
 @Html.Raw(">")
```

the result is deplorable indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the quote characters in C#, not in html. So you'd need to do this:

```
@Html.Raw("<table class=\"table table-togglable table-hover.... ");
```

In other words, put a backslash \ character before every quote you want to appear in the output.

Comment: what if the content is coming from a db table ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the &jquot; and ' entities, They will get translated to the characters for display.